# How can Serializable.class not be assignable from Class.class?

Tags: java, spring, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

In `org.springframework.core.SerializableTypeWrapper` (version 5.2.3), there is the following code at line 112:

```
    if (GraalDetector.inImageCode() || !Serializable.class.isAssignableFrom(Class.class)) {
        // Let's skip any wrapping attempts if types are generally not serializable in
        // the current runtime environment (even java.lang.Class itself, e.g. on Graal)
        return providedType;
    }
```

I'm curious about the second check (`!Serializable.class.isAssignableFrom(Class.class)`): is it possible for it to evaluate to `true` (that is, for `Serialazable.class` to be not assignable from `Class.class`)?

Here is what `Class#isAssignableFrom()` javadoc says:

> Determines if the class or interface represented by this Class object is either the same as, or is a superclass or superinterface of, the class or interface represented by the specified Class parameter.

Looking at the code of `Class`, I see the following:

```
public final class Class<T> implements java.io.Serializable
```

So `Serializable` is a superinterface of `Class` and should *always* be assignable from `Class`. But the check in the Spring code suggests that sometimes it's not.

How come? In what situations can this happen and why don't they violate the Java Language Specification?

Comment: The code comment inside the `if` block would appear relevant: "_Let's skip any wrapping attempts if types are generally not serializable in the current runtime environment (even java.lang.Class itself, e.g. on Graal)_". By "Graal" I assume they mean [GraalVM](https://www.graalvm.org/), which has its [limitations](https://github.com/oracle/graal/blob/master/substratevm/LIMITATIONS.md#serialization) when creating native images. I'm guessing on GraalVM maybe `Class` _does not_ implement `Serializable`? And they use that to test if the current environment is Graal. But I'm not sure.

Comment: @Slaw I've compiled a test program with the following line `System.out.println("Is assignable: " + java.io.Serializable.class.isAssignableFrom(Class.class));`; it outputs `true` both when run with `java` (OpenJDK and GraalVM versions) or when I build a native image from this program with GraalVM's `native-image` tool. So (at least with the current version of Graal), this does not seem to be possible in a native image (unless there are some special conditions...).

Answer (score 2):

A custom [class loader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html) is a possible (if unlikely) mechanism for the expression to return `false`.  Custom class loaders can do some crazy things, including loading their own versions of standard Java classes. Some things to know about class loaders:

- Custom class loaders can be configured to load any class, even including Java standard library classes (it's discouraged of course, but still possible)
- Custom class loaders will typically be configured to delegate to the system class loader for classes that they don't know how to load.
- When class A has a reference to class B, the reference will be resolved using whichever class loader was used to load class A
- More than one class loader can be configured to handle the same class, which can lead to multiple versions of a class getting loaded into the JVM, with the actual implementation you get depending on which class loader you ask

Suppose there is a custom class loader that, for whatever reason, is configured to load `java.io.Serializable` by itself, but delegates to the system class loader for loading other classes, including `java.lang.Class`.

Now suppose this custom class loader is used to load `SerializableTypeWrapper`.  This means it will also be used to resolve the reference to `java.io.Serializable` in `SerializableTypeWrapper`.  With the reference to `java.lang.Class`, the custom class loader will delegate this to the system class loader.  The system class loader will be used to load `java.lang.Class`, but it will also be used to load the reference to `java.io.Serializable` from within `java.lang.Class`.

So now we can ask the question - is `java.io.Serializable [custom]` assignable from `java.lang.Class [standard]`?  And the answer is no - `java.lang.Class` does implement `java.io.Serializable [standard]`, but it does not implement `java.io.Serializable [custom]`.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I wonder what `Class.class instanceof Serializable` would produce in your example. It would probably still be `true` because the right-hand side expression is not a class instance (which may be different for different classloaders) but a class name (at runtime, a member of constant pool, probably), is it correct?

Comment: The RHS must be a reference type, not a simple class name string.  You're right though about it being looked up in the constant pool.  But, the constant pool is per-class, and the lookup is performed using the class loader that loaded the class.  So it would be the same result - it'll return `false` if the `Serializable` known to the class loader is different than the `Serializable` implemented by `Class`.

Comment: JVM spec has some good details, if you're interested: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.instanceof
Also, on class resolution:  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.4.3.1